# Find count, by age, of everyone in database

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with thousands of member records. Each one has a birthdate which is a simple string like "2005-11-01" (yyyy-mm-dd)

I want to query the database and get an idea of the AGE of my members. I'd love to see how many members I have at each age in the db. So I'd love some output like:

```
age         count
---         -----
18          619
19          1321
20          15112
etc.
```

How can I do this? (I'd love to do it all in MySQL but we can add some PHP, Perl or Python if it's easier)

Comment: For those who have voted this down or voted to close it - why the downvotes? This seems like exactly a perfect stackoverflow question... clear question, one clear answer, not subjective etc... ?? I'd love to understand why this is getting the hate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to take care of leap years as well, try something like this:

```
SELECT 
YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(DOB) - (DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%M%D') < DATE_FORMAT(DOB,'%M%D')) `AGE`,
COUNT(*) `COUNT`
FROM YOURTABLE
GROUP BY AGE;
```

Answer (score 2):

You clould use

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '2005-11-01', CURDATE()) AS age , count(*) 
FROM my_table 
group by age ;

SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) AS age , count(*) 
FROM my_table 
group by age ;
```